# HTML Show more button not working on all mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a show more text button that works perfectly fine on the desktop but not on all browsers on the mobile. It works on chrome app but not Samsung internet. Does anyone know why this would be? Is it something to do with the js?

**The code is -**

**JS -**

```
   function myFunction() {
      var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
      var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
      var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

      if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
        moreText.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
      }
    }
```

**CSS -**

```
.moretext{
      display: none;
    }
```

**HTML -**

```
 <div class = "textcontainer">
    <br>
    <br>
    <H3> SHOW YOUR LOVE WITH FLOWERS </H3>
    <p>
    <br>
    When you send flowers, it’s a deeply personal gesture of affection, we realise this well. Receiving a gift of flowers is intensely memorable to someone, because it makes them feel very special and loved. Flowers For Everyone gives you the assurance that we get it right, every time.
    <br>
    <br>
    <span id="dots"></span><span id="more" class="moretext">
    We have a striking range of luxury flower bouquets freshly cut & hand-delivered across the Western Cape province; from Sea Point with its breathtaking sea views and trendy restaurants, to the Cape winelands and beyond, we put smiles to faces. 
    <br>
    <br>
    </span></p>
    </div>

    <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">More...</button>
</div>
```

Comment: apparently, the compatibility with samsung internet is unknown 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: okay.. so is there a workaround?

Comment: you have element.removeAttribute("style") but again there is no full compatibility for IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute